# Assign values to a datetime column in Pandas / Rename a datetime column to a date column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsUDE.png)

I have created the following dataframe 'user_char' in Pandas with:

```
## Create a new workbook User Char with empty datetime columns to import data from the ledger
user_char = all_users[['createdAt', 'uuid','gasType','role']]
## filter on consumers in the user_char table
user_char = user_char[user_char.role == 'CONSUMER']
user_char.set_index('uuid', inplace = True)
## creates datetime columns that need to be added to the existing df
user_char_rng = pd.date_range('3/1/2016', periods = 25, dtype = 'period[M]', freq = 'MS')
## converts date time index to a list
user_char_rng = list(user_char_rng)
## adds empty cols
user_char = user_char.reindex(columns = user_char.columns.tolist() + user_char_rng) 
user_char
```

and I am trying to assign a value to the highlighted column using the following command:

```
user_char['2016-03-01 00:00:00'] = 1
```

but this keeps creating a new column rather than editing the existing one. How do I assign the value 1 to all the indices without adding a new column?

Also how do I rename the datetime column that excludes the timestamp and only leaves the date field in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
user_char.loc[:, '2016-03-01'] = 1
```

Because your column index is a `DatetimeIndex`, pandas is smart enough to translate the string `'2016-03-01'` into datetime format. Using `loc[c]` seems to hint to pandas to first look for `c` in the index, rather than create a new column named `c`.

Side note: the DatetimeIndex of time-series data is conventionally used as the (row) index of a DataFrame, not in the columns. (There's no technical reason why you can't use time in the columns, of course!) In my experience, most of the PyData stack is built to expect "[tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)", where each variable (like time) forms a column, and each observation (timestamp value) forms a row. The way you're doing it, you'll need to transpose your DataFrame before calling `plot()` on it, for example.